# Group specific Filed in Gridview : Aspx web with Vb coding data from SQL DB

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview

I have an `.aspx` page with VB.NET and SQL web in which I have a gridview in which `LPR_NO` is a common column which has in multiple rows.

I wanted to group only LPR_NO in gridview. But when I tried there was an error and asking for all clauses in group by. But it was not my requirement.

My query code

```
SELECT 
    LP_ION.Originator, LP_ION.Originator_ID, LPR_No,  
    Product, LP_ION.AU, LP_ION.Qty_Req, 
    LP_ION.Qty_Issue, LP_ION.Qty_NA, LP_ION.Status AS ION_Status    
FROM 
    LP_ION 
GROUP BY 
    LPR_NO, Product, LP_ION.Originator,
    LP_ION.Originator_ID, LP_ION.AU, LP_ION.Qty_Req, 
    LP_ION.Qty_Issue, LP_ION.Qty_NA, LP_ION.Status
```

I am getting the output like this:

[image: output is like this from the above code]

I want only `LP_ION` to be grouped. Please guide me.

Comment: Not sure I really follow the question.  Perhaps you could refer to [ask] and update your question a bit

Answer (score 0):

First up, that GridView example IS NOT what you get when feeding that SQL example to a GridView. Your GridView screen shot posted shows 2 values on ONE line, and that's not how the GridView normally works.

So, you MUST be leaving out some significant code and details here.

The simple matter is the GridView can ONLY render the final rows of data that your SQL produces. The GridView does NOT have ANY provisions for grouping such data.

As a result, then solutions here will require you the developer to build, cook up, and create your OWN grouping solution by writing some code.

There are several approaches here that can be used.

You can use a repeater, feed that repeater the "list" of groups that you want, and then inside of the repeater then nest the GridView. Thus, for each group, then a whole new GridView object will be rendered. This is rather expensive in terms of processing since for each grouping, a whole new SQL query is required, and a whole new GridView will be rendered. So, for a few groups, then this is a possible solution. For a lot of groups and data, this tends to be too high cost from a processing and that of requiring a whole new SQL query for each group.

Another approach is to "inject" a whole new row into the GridView on row-created event. This again can be done but code is rather convoluted and difficult to write.

For a simple grouping of data? Then I suggest adopting a ListView.

So, this means dumping use of the GridView. You can allow the wizards to create and layout a basic ListView for you. Then simple delete all of the templates generated and only keep the "item template" section.

Or you can use the following markup, and modify for your needs.

So, the solution and process?

Remove the grouping in the SQL as it will not help for this solution.

Simple order the data by the top most group, and then order by whatever you want inside for each group.
Example:
A simple list of Hotels, and we want a grouping by each City.

So, the SQL data source looks like this:

```
 SELECT * FROM tblHotelsA ORDER BY City, HotelName
```

So, we order by the top most group (City), and then order by HotelName for each group as per above.

Now, we only have to "hide" or "show" a grouping row in the ListView when the City value changes.

While the markup for a ListView is a somewhat "more" markup then a GridView, the choice of a ListView is better then a GridView, since the ease in which we can hide/show an extra "grouping row" is why the ListView becomes the better choice here.

So, our markup:

```
<asp:ListView ID="ListView1" runat="server" >
    <ItemTemplate>
        <tr id="MyGroupHeading" runat="server" 
            style="background-color:black;color:white" >
            <td colspan="4">
                <asp:Label ID="lCity" 
                    runat="server" 
                    Text='<%# "Hotels For city = " & Eval("City") %>' />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><asp:Label ID="lFirst" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("FirstName") %>' /></td>
            <td><asp:Label ID="lLast" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("LastName") %>' /></td>
            <td><asp:Label ID="lHotel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("HotelName") %>' /></td>
            <td><asp:Label ID="lDescript" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Description") %>' /></td>
        </tr>
    </ItemTemplate>

    <LayoutTemplate>
        <table id="itemPlaceholderContainer" runat="server" border="0" 
            class="table" style="width:40%" >
            <tr runat="server" style="">
                <th runat="server" style="width:90px">First Name</th>
                <th runat="server" style="width:90px">Last Name</th>
                <th runat="server">Hotel Name</th>
                <th runat="server">Hotel Description</th>
            </tr>
            <tr id="itemPlaceholder" runat="server">
            </tr>
        </table>
    </LayoutTemplate>
</asp:ListView>
```

So, note how we defined TWO "tr" rows for the template. (Bonus advantage of the ListView is you can have more then one row for each record!).

So, code to send data to ListView is this:

```
Dim strMyGroup As String

Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    If IsPostBack = False Then
        loadGrid()
    End If

End Sub

Sub loadGrid()

    strMyGroup = ""

    Dim strSQL As String =
         "SELECT * FROM tblHotelsA ORDER BY City, HotelName"

    ListView1.DataSource = MyRst(strSQL)
    ListView1.DataBind()

End Sub
```

Note close the above variable strMyGroup at the page class level. We will thus have to write code to hide or show the grouping row when City column changes.

And such code is rather simple.

Thus:

```
Protected Sub ListView1_ItemDataBound(sender As Object, e As ListViewItemEventArgs) Handles ListView1.ItemDataBound

    If e.Item.ItemType = ListViewItemType.DataItem Then

        Dim strNewGroup = DirectCast(e.Item.FindControl("lCity"), Label).Text


        Dim MyTr As HtmlTableRow = e.Item.FindControl("MyGroupHeading")
        If strNewGroup <> strMyGroup Then
            ' a new group - 
            strMyGroup = strNewGroup
            MyTr.Visible = True
        Else
            MyTr.Visible = False
        End If

    End If

End Sub
```

And the resulting output is a list of hotels, grouped by City.

[image]

And for completeness, I used a global MyRst routine that is rather handy, and that code simply returns a datatable based on SQL.

Thus:

```
Public Function MyRst(strSQL As String) As DataTable

    Dim rstData As New DataTable
    Using conn As New SqlConnection(My.Settings.TEST4)
        Using cmdSQL As New SqlCommand(strSQL, conn)
            conn.Open()
            rstData.Load(cmdSQL.ExecuteReader)
            rstData.TableName = strSQL
        End Using
    End Using
    Return rstData
End Function
```