# classic ASP - Multidimensionnal array for storing and displaying multiple rows grouped by common fields

Tags: multidimensional-array, display

I've these datas in database

```
COMPANY   | CATEGORY   | BRAND    
--------------------------------
Company 1 | Category 2 | Brand A  
Company 1 | Category 2 | Brand B  
Company 1 | Category 2 | Brand C  
Company 1 | Category 1 | Brand X  
Company 1 | Category 1 | Brand Y  
Company 1 | Category 1 | Brand Z  
Company 1 | Category 3 | Brand A  
Company 1 | Category 3 | Brand X
```

I would like to display them in this way :

**COMPANY 1**

- CATEGORY 1:

BRAND X

BRAND Y

BRAND Z

- CATEGORY 2

BRAND A

BRAND B

BRAND C

- CATEGORY 3

BRAND A

BRAND X

In php, it's easy :

1. first loop to put database results in a multidimensionnal array
2. second loop to display the array

```
  while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $companies[$row['company']][$row['category']][] = $row['brand'];
  }

  foreach ($companies AS $company => $categories) {
    echo '<h2>'. htmlentities($company, ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8') .'</h2>';
    echo '<ul>';
    foreach ($categories AS $category => $brands) {
      echo '<li>'. htmlentities($category, ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8');
      foreach ($brands AS $brand) {
        echo '<br><em>'. htmlentities($brand, ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8') .'</em>';
      }
      echo '<br>&nbsp;</li>';
    }
    echo '</ul>';
  }
```

But in classic asp, how to have a multidimensionnal array ?

with array of array ? Dictionnary of arrays ? Dictionnary of Dictionnaries ?

Comment: How "classic" are you talking about here? Is this a webforms app, and do you have use of say GridView, or ListView?

Comment: classic is for ASP language. I've changed the title.

Comment: Ok, I my skill set does not go back that far! That's awful old stuff. I don't even know what kind of server controls you have as a choice here. Maybe I fire up VS and see if I can get a older template working. If you have use of ListView, then I am happy to post a grouping example here.

Comment: We plan to migrate under PHP. But it is not our priority for the moment.
And we still have to ensure a minimum of maintenance, unfortunately in asp :-(

Comment: Well, if you had even a older webforms, then you don't even need to write looping code. I as noted just have not worked with such a older system. So, you would not need to send or convert the data pull to a array, but could and would use a datatable. An recent example of grouping hotels by city can be seen in this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76750963/group-specific-filed-in-gridview-aspx-web-with-vb-coding-data-from-sql-db/76762454#76762454

Comment: So, as above shows? We not even had to write any loops!

Comment: I don't know why the asp.net tag was added. - It's not relative to asp.net, but classic asp langage

Comment: Ok, the title can be confusing, I changed it - The problem is for storing datas in a multidimensionnal array in classic asp.

Comment: No worries, and in fact this is much my fault, since I don't know what features are available in such older systems. I could "segway" and suggest that converting to webforms might be rather little work, and that would open up use of all those cool data bound controls (ListView, GridView, Repeater) all of which can be feed data directly without having to write loops. However, as noted, upgrading to a later version of .net not likely a practical option.  I'm just out of my realm here, and don't know the limitations of these very old classic asp web page systems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After several hours to test some code, i ask to ChatGPT

```
classic ASP - get data from database and display them in a 5 depth list
I've these column datas in database

Niveau1 | Niveau2| Niveau3| Niveau4| Niveau5

I would like to display them in list group by Niveau5, inside list group by Niveau4, inside list group by Niveau3, inside list group by Niveau2, inside list group by Niveau1
```

The answer is OK

```
    <%
' Step 1: Retrieve data from the database (assuming you have already connected to the database and have a recordset called "rs")

' Create a nested data structure to hold the hierarchical data
Dim data
Set data = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

' Loop through the recordset and organize the data into the nested structure
Do While Not rs.EOF
    Dim niveau1, niveau2, niveau3, niveau4, niveau5
    niveau1 = rs("Niveau1")
    niveau2 = rs("Niveau2")
    niveau3 = rs("Niveau3")
    niveau4 = rs("Niveau4")
    niveau5 = rs("Niveau5")

    ' Check if the niveau1 key exists in the data dictionary
    If Not data.Exists(niveau1) Then
        data.Add niveau1, CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    End If

    ' Check if the niveau2 key exists in the niveau1 dictionary
    If Not data(niveau1).Exists(niveau2) Then
        data(niveau1).Add niveau2, CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    End If

    ' Check if the niveau3 key exists in the niveau2 dictionary
    If Not data(niveau1)(niveau2).Exists(niveau3) Then
        data(niveau1)(niveau2).Add niveau3, CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    End If

    ' Check if the niveau4 key exists in the niveau3 dictionary
    If Not data(niveau1)(niveau2)(niveau3).Exists(niveau4) Then
        data(niveau1)(niveau2)(niveau3).Add niveau4, CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    End If

    ' Add niveau5 to the niveau4 dictionary
    data(niveau1)(niveau2)(niveau3)(niveau4).Add niveau5, Nothing

    rs.MoveNext
Loop

' Step 3: Generate the HTML list from the nested data structure
Sub GenerateList(data, depth)
    If depth > 0 Then
        Response.Write("<ul>")
    End If

    For Each key In data.Keys
        Response.Write("<li>" & key & "</li>")
        If IsObject(data(key)) Then
            GenerateList data(key), depth + 1
        End If
    Next

    If depth > 0 Then
        Response.Write("</ul>")
    End If
End Sub

' Start generating the list from the top level (Niveau1)
GenerateList data, 0
%>
```